# Difference compilation VS 2015 and VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, compilation, eazfuscator

I have a free .Net 4.0 app that protect with Eazfuscator v3.3 (last free version). All the classes in my single project app are internal. I use symbol encryption to encrypt class names, methods and members. Up until now, everything was encrypted

Up until now, I was using VS 2010, and everything worked fine. I switched to VS 2015, still targeting .Net 4.0 framework. Once the code is compiled and obfuscated, using reflector I can clearly see class names in clear (but methods and members are still encrypted)

Is there anything different between VS 2010 compilation and VS 2015 compilation if both target .Net 4.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2015 uses Roslyn compiler. It produces different instructions and metadata and this affects the analysis engine in Eazfuscator.NET 3.3.

Eazfuscator.NET 3.3 cannot work with assemblies produced by VS 2015 or newer.

The support for Visual Studio 2015 was added in Eazfuscator.NET 4.9, so you need at least that version to successfully obfuscate the assemblies produced by Roslyn compilers.